# how to convert sql query to hibernate query

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jpa

i have q sql query where i am fetching data using subquery and left join. it is working properly on sql server but when i use  this query in hibernate using HQL it says unexpected token (;

**below is my query which is working fine on sql server** -

```
SELECT IH.vendorName, IH.C, IHP.CP FROM (SELECT vendorName, count(*) as C 
FROM InvoiceHeader GROUP BY vendorName) IH LEFT JOIN (SELECT vendorName, 
count(*) AS CP FROM InvoiceHeader WHERE invoiceStatus='Processed' GROUP BY 
vendorName) IHP ON IHP.vendorName=IH.vendorName ORDER BY IH.C DESC
```

here i am trying to convert my sql query to HQL

```
Query q = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("SELECT 
IH.vendorName, IH.C, IHP.CP FROM (SELECT vendorName, count(*) as C FROM 
InvoiceHeader GROUP BY vendorName) IH LEFT JOIN (SELECT vendorName, count(*) 
AS CP FROM InvoiceHeader WHERE invoiceStatus='Processed' GROUP BY 
vendorName) IHP ON IHP.vendorName=IH.vendorName ORDER BY IH.C DESC");
```

**but i am getting this error at**

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
ERROR: line 1:41: unexpected token: (
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
ERROR: line 1:61: unexpected token: count
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's partially how to do it.

First, your query needs to be simplified, because the joins are not at all efficient. MSSQL does not support FILTER, but [Modern SQL](https://modern-sql.com/feature/filter) shows us a sufficent alternative.

```
SELECT vendorName, sum(case when invoiceStatus = 'Processed' then 1 end) as CP, count(*) as C FROM InvoiceHeader GROUP BY vendorName ORDER BY C DESC;
```

Secondly you could use `createNativeQuery` if it turns out to be impossible to translate it to HQL, but this is my attempt to do so:

```
SELECT I.vendorName, COUNT(I) as C, SUM(CASE WHEN I.invoiceStatus = 'Processed' THEN 1 END) AS CP FROM InvoiceHeader I GROUP BY I.vendorName ORDER BY C DESC
```

It is important you use the table alias, so that it will resolve properly within the query, even though it's the only table.

Comment: thank you very much..now i got the query which is working fine